# Simple RoR Drop-down box, passing values through as params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, parameter-passing

I'm trying to create a drop-down box with a few values.
I don't want it to be part of a form_for, since I'll just be passing the values through to the next page as params.

It seems like there should be a simple way to do this, but I'm not seeing it.

Or do I basically have to use a form_for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `select_tag` helper, section 3 of [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), and at `options_for_select` and `options_from_collection_for_select`, used in conjuction with it.

Comment: Thanks! Between that and http://www.saalonmuyo.com/2010/01/27/using-form_tag-in-ruby-on-rails/ I was able to get it worked out.
However, I can't get the submit button to submit to the path designated in the form_tag.  It doesn't seem to do anything at all.  Any ideas?

Comment: A bit late, but... unless you've set the form to remote or the submit button isn't actually inside the form, I can't think how it would do _nothing_. Check your server log, perhaps?

Comment: I had a line break in the form_tag, but didn't have it indented into the form.  This caused the form to break off at the line break, rendering everything after it outside of the form.  Hence, the submit didn't work.  Easy fix!

Answer (score 2):

form_for expects you'll have a model that you are constructing the form for.

Check out the form_tag where you'll give it the URL/path and then you can have a select_tag to send params to the next page.